# Collapse/Un-collapse all menu items. - HTML/JS/CSS/Bootstrap3

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

The left is what my code does, the right is what I want it to do. When clicking on a menu item it collapses fine but I want to be able to un-collapse them after and be able to collapse all of them if I wish.

[image]

```
    $('.nav-second').on('show.bs.collapse', function () {
        $('.nav-second.in').collapse('hide');
    });
```

html

```
<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div id="sidebar-wrapper">
    <ul class="sidebar-nav">
        <li class="sidebar-brand"></li>
        <li>
            <a href="main.html"><i class="material-icons">home</i></a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#overall" data-toggle="collapse" aria expanded="false">Overall </a>
            <ul id="overall" class="nav-second collapse">
                <li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Item 2</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#dashboard" data-toggle="collapse" aria expanded="false">Dashboard </a>
            <ul id="dashboard" class="nav-second collapse">
                <li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Item 2</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#service" data-toggle="collapse" aria expanded="false">Service </a>
            <ul id="service" class="nav-second collapse">
                <li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Item 2</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
    </ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need this approach just remove that jQuery code.

I mean this one:

```
$('.nav-second').on('show.bs.collapse', function () {
        $('.nav-second.in').collapse('hide');
    });
```

Comment: I tried that already, works for being able to collapse all the menu items but the un-collapse don't work. Thanks for your time

Comment: What do you need to un-collapse at all.

Comment: .collapse("toggle") Toggles the collapsible element 
.collapse("show") Shows the collapsible element 
.collapse("hide") Hides the collapsible element

I think i need the collapse toggle but not sure where to put it